# test and strip characters from jquery result for fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox

```
$.fancybox.open({
    helpers: {
        title: {
            type: 'inside'
        },
        buttons: {}
                    },
                    padding : 0,
                    href: $('#url').val(),
.......
```

I would like to check the value of href: and strip http: and https: from the result. I am not really that great with jquery and javascript and even less with something like fancybox.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a split/slice/join

```
$('#url').val().split('://').slice( $('#url').val().split('://').length-1 ).join('')
```

like this

```
$.fancybox.open({
    helpers: {
      title: {
          type: 'inside'
      },
      buttons: {}
                  },
                  padding : 0,
                  href: $('#url').val().split('://').slice( $('#url').val().split('://').length-1 ).join(''),
.......
```

Below sample shows how to and make sure it won't break if there is no protocol

```js
console.log( $('#url').val().split('://').slice( $('#url').val().split('://').length-1 ).join('') )

console.log( $('#url2').val().split('://').slice( $('#url2').val().split('://').length-1 ).join('') )
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="url" value="http://some.data.com">
<input id="url2" value="some.data.com">
```

Answer (score 0):

I really shouldn't have bothered asking the question. I figured it out on my own. 
I ended up doing it like this:

```
var url = $('#url').val();
if (url.substring(0, 5) == 'https') { 
    url = url.substring(6);
} elseif (url.substring(0, 4) == 'http') { 
    url = url.substring(5);
}
```

and then just using

```
href: url,
```